# SQL pivot with summary and average aggregation

Tags: sql-server, pivot, average, aggregate-functions, summary

I am using the following SQL code to generate the output which is attached as well.

The output is a pivot with interval numbers (1 to 13, referring to time intervals of 4 weeks) with a summary aggregation next to it for the current year and last year.

I need to expand this result with and extra aggregation for current year and last year, representing the averages (Interval 1: 53 and 48, interval 2: 64 and 46, interval 3: 65.7 and 57.3, etc).

Can anybody help me out to achieve this please? Your help is more than welcome!

Best regards!

```
DECLARE @ThisYear CHAR(4)
SET @ThisYear = 2017
DECLARE @LastYear CHAR(4)
SET @LastYear = @ThisYear - 1
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = '
WITH ranked AS
  (
    SELECT
      per.UserPeriod1 as Year,
      per.UserPeriod2 as Interval,
      count(distinct(a.ProductNummer)) as nr
    FROM
      Periode per
      left join klacht k
        join Artikel a on a.ArtikelNummer = k.ArtikelNummer        
       on k.KlachtDatum = per.DateValue
    where per.UserPeriod1 between ' + @LastYear + ' and ' + @ThisYear + '                    
   group by per.UserPeriod1, per.UserPeriod2
  )
 SELECT Interval, ThisYear = [' + @ThisYear + '], LastYear = [' + @LastYear + ']
    FROM ranked
    PIVOT (SUM(nr) FOR Year IN ([' + @ThisYear + '], [' + @LastYear + '])) AS p
';
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: `... ThisYear = [' + @ThisYear + '], LastYear = [' + @LastYear + '], avg = ([' + @ThisYear + '] + [' + @LastYear + '])/2 ...`

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: The DBMS is SQL Server...